# Как выровнять текст при выводе в python

Tags: python, строки

Нужно чтобы при выводе в консоль, текст отображался примерно таким образом:

```
[text1   ]: hello.
[text23  ]: hello..
[text123 ]: hello.
[text0   ]: hello...
```

Чтобы количество пробелов было в зависимости от текста в квадратных скобках, и всё что после двоеточия было в один столбец. Как это можно реализовать проще?

Comment: пропишите через \t. `[text1\t]: hello.`

Comment: '{:*^10}'.format('text')  попробуйте форматировать строку заранее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Код

```
prefixes=\
( "text1",
  "text12",
  "text123",
  "text0")

messages=\
( "hello.",
 "hello..",
 "hello.",
 "hello...")

width=max(map(len, prefixes))
for p, m in zip(prefixes, messages):
    print("[%s]: " % p.ljust(width), m, sep='')
```

### Примечание

- В строке `[text123 ]: hello.` я посчитал пробел после `text123` лишним, но его можно добавить (`width += 1`).
- `map(len, prefixes)` - все длины `prefixes` (`<map object at ...>`)

Answer (score 4):

```
In [23]: samples = ["test1", "test12", "test123"]

In [24]: max_indent = len(max(samples, key=len)) + 1

In [25]: for sample in samples:
    ...:     print(f"[{sample:<{max_indent}}]: hello")
    ...:
[test1   ]: hello
[test12  ]: hello
[test123 ]: hello
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listText = ['text1','text11','text111','text1111','1234567891011515151']
listText2 = ['test','test','test','test','ga']
lenElementsMass = []
for i in range(len(listText)):
    lenElementsMass.append(len(listText[i]))
lenMass = len(listText)
max = int(max(lenElementsMass)) + 2
for i in range(lenMass):
    text = "[" + listText[i] + "]"
    while True:
        if len(text) < max:
            text = text[0:-1] + " " + text[-1]
        else:
            break
    print(text + " " + listText2[i])
```

вывод:

```
[text1              ] test
[text11             ] test
[text111            ] test
[text1111           ] test
[1234567891011515151] ga
```